# Resolution and scaling issues on dual monitor with nvidia (one 4k HiDPI, one VGA with converter)

Tags: xorg, nvidia, multi-monitor, xrandr, high-dpi

I am trying Kubuntu 18.10 and I have a nvidia GTX 1060 (driver 418), a LG 27" 4k monitor (27UD58-B ) and an older HP 22" 1680x1050 monitor (HPw2207) with a VGA cord and a VGA-> DP converter.

My issues are as follow:
1)  I can't get my vga screen with converter to use a resolution above 1280*1024

2)  I'd like to use screen scaling because everything is so damn small on the 4k display.  I'd want the scaling to only be done on the high-dpi display if possible.

**Current setup:**

I am using Nvidia drivers 418.56.

```
$ nvidia-smi
Mon Apr 15 15:07:47 2019       
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 418.56       Driver Version: 418.56       CUDA Version: 10.1     |
|-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name        Persistence-M| Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp  Perf  Pwr:Usage/Cap|         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|===============================+======================+======================|
|   0  GeForce GTX 106...  Off  | 00000000:23:00.0  On |                  N/A |
| 10%   64C    P0    25W / 120W |    739MiB /  6076MiB |      3%      Default |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+

+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Processes:                                                       GPU Memory |
|  GPU       PID   Type   Process name                             Usage      |
|=============================================================================|
|    0       958      G   /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg                           386MiB |
|    0      1413      G   /usr/bin/kwin_x11                            192MiB |
|    0      1432      G   /usr/bin/krunner                               1MiB |
|    0      1434      G   /usr/bin/plasmashell                         111MiB |
|    0      1509      G   /usr/bin/latte-dock                           29MiB |
|    0      9387      G   /usr/lib/firefox/firefox                       1MiB |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

and normal higher resolutions are not available:

```
$ xrandr
Screen 0: minimum 8 x 8, current 4864 x 2160, maximum 32767 x 32767
DVI-D-0 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
HDMI-0 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-0 connected primary 3840x2160+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 600mm x 340mm
   3840x2160     60.00*+  30.00  
   2560x1440     59.95  
   1920x1080     60.00    59.94  
   1600x900      60.00  
   1280x1024     60.02  
   1280x800      59.81  
   1280x720      60.00    59.94  
   1152x864      59.96  
   1024x768      60.00  
   800x600       60.32  
   720x480       59.94  
   640x480       59.94    59.93  
DP-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-2 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-3 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-4 connected 1024x1280+3840+832 left (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 376mm x 301mm
   1280x1024     60.02*+
   1280x960      60.00  
   1152x864      75.00  
   1024x768      85.00    75.03    70.07    60.00  
   800x600       85.06    75.00    72.19  
   640x480       85.01    59.94  
DP-5 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
```

**First issue: fixing resolution**
I have tried to "addmode" using xrandr, but I get a BadMatch error. This is apparently normal with nvidia video cards.

```
$ cvt 1680 1050 60
# 1680x1050 59.95 Hz (CVT 1.76MA) hsync: 65.29 kHz; pclk: 146.25 MHz
Modeline "1680x1050_60.00"  146.25  1680 1784 1960 2240  1050 1053 1059 1089 -hsync +vsync
$ xrandr --newmode  "1680x1050_60.00"  146.25  1680 1784 1960 2240  1050 1053 1059 1089 -hsync +vsync

$ xrandr --addmode DP-4 1680x1050_60.00
X Error of failed request:  BadMatch (invalid parameter attributes)
  Major opcode of failed request:  140 (RANDR)
  Minor opcode of failed request:  18 (RRAddOutputMode)
  Serial number of failed request:  45
  Current serial number in output stream:  46
```

My /etc/X11/xorg.conf file has been generated by nvidia usind sudo nvidia-xconfig :

```
$ sudo nvidia-xconfig

Using X configuration file: "/etc/X11/xorg.conf".
Backed up file '/etc/X11/xorg.conf' as '/etc/X11/xorg.conf.backup'
New X configuration file written to '/etc/X11/xorg.conf'
```

The xorg.conf only contains one monitor, is this normal.  I have tried to add a "Modeline" line under the Monitor0, but it didnt change anything.

```
# nvidia-xconfig: X configuration file generated by nvidia-xconfig
# nvidia-xconfig:  version 418.56


Section "ServerLayout"
    Identifier     "Layout0"
    Screen      0  "Screen0" 0 0
    InputDevice    "Keyboard0" "CoreKeyboard"
    InputDevice    "Mouse0" "CorePointer"
EndSection

Section "Files"
EndSection

Section "InputDevice"

    # generated from default
    Identifier     "Mouse0"
    Driver         "mouse"
    Option         "Protocol" "auto"
    Option         "Device" "/dev/psaux"
    Option         "Emulate3Buttons" "no"
    Option         "ZAxisMapping" "4 5"
EndSection

Section "InputDevice"

    # generated from default
    Identifier     "Keyboard0"
    Driver         "kbd"
EndSection

Section "Monitor"
    Identifier     "Monitor0"
    VendorName     "Unknown"
    ModelName      "Unknown"
    HorizSync       28.0 - 33.0
    VertRefresh     43.0 - 72.0
    Option         "DPMS"
EndSection

Section "Device"
    Identifier     "Device0"
    Driver         "nvidia"
    VendorName     "NVIDIA Corporation"
EndSection

Section "Screen"
    Identifier     "Screen0"
    Device         "Device0"
    Monitor        "Monitor0"
    DefaultDepth    24
    SubSection     "Display"
        Depth       24
    EndSubSection
EndSection
```

**Second issue : scaling**

I have taken two steps to allow the HiDPI screen to display text and GUI in a more readable size:

1)  System settings - fonts - Force Font DPI 144 (instead of 96)
2)  system settings- display and monitors - scale display 1.5 (instead of 1).

I would lke these settings to only apply to the 4k monitor, is this possible at all?

Answer (score 0):

I found a workaround: I connected my display directly to an old tower that has a VGA and exported the edid using

```
sudo apt install read-edid
sudo get-edid -m 0 > edid.bin
```

then I erased the old xorg.conf on the machine and created a new one where I forced the edid for the monitor on display port 4:

```
sudo rm /etc/X11/xorg.conf 
nvidia-xconfig --custom-edid="GPU-0.DP-4:/home/MYNAME/edid.bin"
```

Ta-da, the higher resolution now works.   When I look at my xorg.conf file, I see the following line has been added to the "Screen" section:

```
   Option         "CustomEDID" "GPU-0.DP-4:/home/MYNAME/Downloads/edid.bin"
```

here is what I ended up doing regarding the scaling with a high-dpi monitor and a standard-dpi monitor:

Ok, mais là tout est trop gros sur le 22” .. il faut que je rescale de 1.4 dans la direction inverse.
Ça me fait un écran de 3840 + 1.4 * 1680 = 6192 pixels de large, que je dois indiquer dans le frame buffer.
Ensuite, j’indique la position des écrans avec --pos, où le 0x0 est le coin haut-gauche de l’écran.
https://askubuntu.com/questions/393400/is-it-possible-to-have-different-dpi-configurations-for-two-different-screens
xrandr --output DP-0 --scale 1x1 --pos 0x0 --fb 6192x2160
xrandr --output DP-4 --scale 1.4x1.4 --pos 3840x690